# How to get cookies in Nextjs api routes?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am building a note-taking app in Next.Js and MongoDB. I have created a login system that allows users to create an account and log in to create notes.

For authentication, I am using JWT. When the user logs in the cookie will be created with the name `jwtToken`. The **Token** contains `name`, and `email`.

I have created an API called `createNote` in `/api/createNote.js`. Inside the API route, I want to access cookies `jwtToken` in order to authenticate whether the user is logged in or not before going next.

In `/api/createNote.js` I access the cookie (jwt token) and decode it to get the `email`.

```
const token = req.cookies.jwtToken;
const data = jwt.decode(token);
const email = data.email;
```

I don't see any error while logging `email` to the console or just sending it as JSON like `res.json({data})`. This works but actually problem occurs when I am using it inside `if` statement.

[browser-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrwCL.png)

Here is the code:

```
if(!email){
res.json({msg: "Your are not logged in! Please login first.})
}else if(email){
// do something
}
```

I see this `error` in console:

[error-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqHxh.png)

### Note

The problem only occurs when I use `email` in the if statement. I don't know why. Please help me where is the bug or how to solve it.

Comment: Try to use Optional Chaining.  Use this Code instead
const email = data?.email;

Comment: I have tried this. The error is gone but data is not being saved to the DB.

Comment: The error means the `data` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // data itself could be null
 // if data is null and data.email will throw error
 const data = jwt.decode(token);
  
   
  if (!data.email) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      msg: "Your are not logged in! Please login first."
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am not using `Typescript`. Can you update the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
const token = req.cookies.get('your_cookie_name')?.value || "" // because the value might be null
let email;
if(token){
const {email} = jwt.verify(token, YOUR_TOKEN_SECRET);
email = email // or email
}

if(!email){
await res.json({msg: "Your are not logged in! Please login 
first.})
}else if(email){
// do something
}
```